# Adding rows in DataGridView by time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a Windows Forms application.
There is a DataGridView on a form.  I set a timer which checks the records in a table after an interval, and if a time condition met, it adds rows to the DataGridView.

Is there another method to accomplish this (without using a timer and without looping through the database?

Comment: Do you mean that your application is polling the database for new data?  If you don't want to poll, you'd have to implement some kind of event notification/subscription infrastructure which is very much more complex and off the top of my head would involve holes in the firewall, middle-tier or triggers/CLR code on the db server, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a way to do this.  Polling the table is pretty much you're only path here.  You'd have to find some way to hook into the DB server's event model.  May or may not be possible depending on which DB server you are using.